# How to avoid receiving "Enter Parameter Value" when using access to update certain data

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to execute the following sql

```
UPDATE (SELECT a.Volumn, b.Out_1 FROM A_Temp as a,Volume as b
WHERE a.Dates = b.Dates 
AND b.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Out_1%')
SET a.Volumn = b.Out_1
```

I want to find a column with name 'Out_1' and update the data of this column into another table. But each time, I was asked to enter b.column_name. How can I avoid this set?

I plan further to use matlab automatically exec all sqls.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to search the column titles for a column with a name like `%Out_1%`?  If that is the case it will not work because your query is treating `b.COLUMN_NAME` as if that is the name of your column.

When you enter the name of a column that does not exist in a query, access assumes it is a parameter and asks you if you want to enter a value.  If you are trying to update a column in one table with a column in another table you will require a query that performs a `JOIN`.

`UPDATE [A_Temp] INNER JOIN Volume ON [A_Temp].Dates = Volume.Dates SET [A_Temp].Volumn = Volume.[Out_1]`